# Map Control+Delete to Forward Delete

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

I use a wireless Apple keyboard at home and a wired (full sized) one at work. Now I constantly get confused when I want to do a forward delete, since I'm used to the <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> combination.

Is it possible to somehow map <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> to do the same thing? (<kbd>control</kbd> is in the same location as <kbd>fn</kbd> on the full size keyboard)

Comment: [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) might be able to do that, not tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) with a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Forward Delete with ⌃⌫</name>
    <identifier>private.ctrlbackspace</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::DELETE, VK_CONTROL | ModifierFlag::NONE,
      KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: I didn't even need a custom XML, there is already a setting in Karabiner for that in the `Change Delete Key` section under `Control+Delete to Forward Delete`

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) you can import one of the predefined rules that are maintained by the community, or look at the JSON definition of those to see how it's done.

For example the "*Map Ctrl+Backspace-Delete to Fn+Backward-Delete (suppr current character)*" rule.

See https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=Map%20Ctrl%2BBackspace-Delete